# Submitting a HTML form and download the file

Tags: c#, forms, download, submit

I'm an amateur astronomer.
I developed a window application in C# with many features.
A new one I would like to implement is the automation of the download of sky sections (coordinates and field of view degrees are input parameters) via ESO DSS site and display in a PictureBox inside my program.

What I basically need to do is to fill the appropriate text boxes here: http://archive.eso.org/dss/dss and triggers the "Retrieve Image" button.
Once you press this button a file is downloaded on your machine

As said, my app is in C#. 
Is this kind of automation feasible and how?

Comment: Normally you'd take a look at what the form does, and recreate the form rather than try automate inputting into a random web browser

Comment: If the target service has an API, using that would be preferable.  Check their documentation for that.  If they don't, you can "pretend to be a web browser" in code by making HTTP requests and reading the responses.  This may involve using your browser's debugging tools to reverse-engineer the steps you need to perform.  Your goal would be to recreate the HTTP request (probably a POST) performed by submitting that form, and then reading the response in code.  Classes like `WebClient` are very useful for this.

Comment: Ok. So the correct approach is to try to recreate the form and submit it via code in C#. Try to have a look at something similar. Thanks

Comment: The form is submitting this GET request : `http://archive.eso.org/dss/dss/image?ra=&dec=&equinox=J2000&name=&x=5&y=5&Sky-Survey=DSS1&mime-type=download-fits&statsmode=WEBFORM` - You can use the WebRequest object to achieve this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks Steve. It is exactly what I was looking form: a URL string with the input parameters but I wasn't able to find it...Just for sake of curiosity, how did you find it ?

Comment: I used Chromes dev-tools to see where the form was being submitted.

Comment: Meanwhile I built the C# code using WebRequest and it works. Thread can be successfully closed. Thanks

Comment: If you want another way of finding out, looking at the page source it shows where it was being sent, and the options and variables involved